# Im looking to start a specific application using intent in android studio

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio

I am looking to start a specific application(Dictionary app) from my app. Using intents, how would I go about launching that specific app and use it to look up the word.

Comment: Contact the developers of the app and ask them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `implicit intents` and `explicit intents`, you want an **explicit** intent to get your desirable.

Here is how you can do it.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.MyExampleActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

in the `setComponent` method your Dictionary app information should go in.

CommonsWare addition to this answer,

Using an explicit Intent to talk to a third-party app is rarely the right thing to do. This code will break if the activity is not **exported**, or requires **permissions**, or the developer refactors the code and **changes the class name or package**, etc.

If the author of the app is documenting that your recipe is the correct way to work with that activity on that app, then that is fine, as the developer presumably intends to support this use case.

Comment: Using an explicit `Intent` to talk to a third-party app is rarely the right thing to do. This code will break if the activity is not exported, or requires permissions, or the developer refactors the code and changes the class name or package, etc. If the author of the app is documenting that your recipe is the correct way to work with that activity on that app, then that is fine, as the developer presumably intends to support this use case.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, You are right on, I will add this to my answer :).